# How to filter elements inside a XML node from transforming using XSLT?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an XML using XSLT but need to avoid the elements inside a particular node from being transformed. How can I achieve that?

My current XSLT modifies all the nodes. Below is my XML and I need to avoid all the elements in `<Makers>` node from being transformed:

```
<Data>
       <Makers>
            <Type>ABC</Type>
            </Set>
            <Block>
                <FirstName>ZSPZCVCR</FirstName>
                <LastName/>
            </Block>
        </Makers>
        <Keeper>
            <Code>12</Node>
            <Name>Division</Name>
            <Number/>
            <Company/>
        </Keeper>
</Data>
```

Below is my XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>      
    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)][not(normalize-space())]">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:text>12345</xsl:text>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please provide any solution or suggest a way to modify existing XSLT to avoid all the elements of `<Makers>` from getting modified.

The desired output should be like below where any empty node inside `<Makers>` is not modified but outside that all the empty nodes are modified with value "12345":

```
<Data>
       <Makers>
            <Type>ABC</Type>
            </Set>
            <Block>
                <FirstName>ZSPZCVCR</FirstName>
                <LastName/>
            </Block>
        </Makers>
        <Keeper>
            <Code>12</Node>
            <Name>Division</Name>
            <Number>12345</Number>
            <Company>12345</Company>
        </Keeper>
</Data>
```

Comment: How should the desired output look like?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I modified my question to show the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add a predicate:

```
[not(ancestor::Makers)]
```

to your second template. Such as

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)][not(normalize-space())][not(ancestor::Makers)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:text>12345</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to add the template rule

```
<xsl:template match="Makers" priority="5">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

To me this seems clearer than Joel's solution.

Comment: Hey Michael, Just a question. What is priority implies here? I mean how did you come up with value 5 for it? If you could provide me some link I can refer then that would also do. Just for the sake of my understanding. Thanks!

Comment: The default priority for the pattern `match="*[....]"` is 0.5, and the default priority for `match="Makers"` is 0. To make sure that the second pattern is chosen when both patterns match, we must give it a priority greater than 0.5. So long as it's greater than 0.5, any number will do.